# getYear(), getMonth(), getDay are deprecated in Calendar, what to use then?

Tags: android, date, time, calendar

I want to parse a date from a string and set it in the DatePickerDialog:

```
try {
    myCalendar.setTime(mySimpleFormatter.parse(jsonObj.getString("dob")));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println("!!!");
}

myEditBox.setText(mySimpleFormatter.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
myDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().updateDate(myCalendar.getTime().getYear()); // depricated
```

But the issue is that myCalendar.getTime().getYear(), getMonth(), getDay are deprecated. What should be used then?

Answer (score 19):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(myDate);
int day= cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Answer (score 2):

the `Date.getYear(), getMonth() and getDay()` are **deprecated** and specifically ask you to use `Calendar.get()`

Here is the relevant note from the API documentation

Deprecated. As of `JDK version 1.1,` replaced by Calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 1900.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getYear%28%29

I have used this code :

```
private void setDateTimeField(){
        usereditbirthdateedittext.setOnClickListener(this);

        Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

                SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                usereditbirthdateedittext.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));

                selectedDate = new Date(newDate.getTimeInMillis());
            }

        },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin solution :**

```
Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH + 1)
```

The value returned  from `get(Calendar.MONTH)` is between 0 and 11, with the value 0 representing January, so you need to add +1 to get the current month.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)+1`?

Answer (score -1):

You're actually calling methods on Date, which are deprecated.  (myCalendar.getDate() returns a Date object).

On an instance of Calendar, you can use [get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#get%28int%29) and pass it constants to get year, month, date, and more (refer to the linked docs for get()).

Answer (score -3):

I will recommend you to use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) instead as it is more powerful and can solve all of the Date related issues.

Here is the example sample:

```
DateTimeFormatter fromFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"); // String pattern of your DOB from which you want to create DateTime Object
DateTime dob = fromFormat.parseDateTime(jsonObj.getString("dob")); // This will give you DateTime Object 
DateTimeFormatter toFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMMM dd, yyyy"); // String pattern of your parsed DOB
myEditBox.setText(dob.toString(toFormat)); // April 2, 2016
myDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().updateDate(dob.getYear());
```

Comment: JodaTime adds ~8k methods to your method count, so using it for simple stuff like getDay/Month/Year() is an overkill.